# What does it mean when you are asked to specify artwork scale?

Tags: print-design, resolution

So I am preparing a couple of small adverts and the specifications for the artwork ask that :

"Please specify which scale ie. 10% 25% 50%, and as individual artworks ie.
Panel A, Panel B etc..."

So my question is what does this mean?

I must admit I lack print experience and have never come across this requirement before, however despite quite a bit of goggling I wasnt able to find out what this means.

does it mean that if I have a document that is 500x500mm, 300dpi, CMYK (Which is what they asked for) its 100% resolution?

Apologies if this is a noob question but I just cant find any other sources on the web.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For our printing partners, we almost exclusively submit PDFs for printing.
Unfortunately, PDFs have dimension limits. It was around 5 meters (I Googled, it's 200 inches). So we scale down.**

We usually do it for those **hoarding** artworks -- **hoardings** are "panels" that you use to board up when you're constructing a new store inside a mall (or any building construction...)

[image: Banana Republic building facade hoarding]
[Hoarding example 1](http://omnicolour.com/showcase/fashion--retail/banana-republic)

[image: Just some hoarding...]
[Hoarding example 2](http://www.projectprintmanagement.co.uk/recent-projects/cost-printed-building-site-hoardings/)

[image: ... another hoarding example...]
[Hoarding example 3](http://www.gqdesign.com/news.asp). This one would have 6 separate panels or two long ones (if you just fold the sides, no cutting).

**We always work on InDesign, then export to PDF. For hoarding artworks, we default to doing it at 10% the actual size (example, for 500cm x 100cm we scale it down to 50x10cm).**

The panels they mentioned probably refer to the panels for some sort of hoarding panels, or large stickers...

**EXAMPLES** (actual contact sheets):

- [Google Drive link example 1 - stickers for Marks & Spencer London
  bus - by
  colleague](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_WfzE-MrS0rQkVkV2xIdkQ3NFE/view?usp=sharing)
- [Google Drive link example 2 - for Nine West glass panels stickers -
  by
  colleague](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_WfzE-MrS0rcG1lRkd5Yk5IQTg/view?usp=sharing)
- [Google Drive link example 3 - submitted to us by brand partner
  Garage, for our
  reference](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_WfzE-MrS0rVDZwckJNMGw4eE0/view?usp=sharing)

NOTES:

- When you submit your artwork, be sure to make a contact sheet like the linked examples above :') Label the artworks properly.
- If you scale down, you **may or may NOT need to compensate** for the dpi that would also be "scaled down" (i.e., a 10% 300ppi image would be
  30ppi only when scaled to 100% for print.) It depends on where it's
  gonna be installed, or your printer's ppi capacity... etc. Talk to
  your printer. Have coffee or tea with them :')

Best wishes! :')

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell this is really the case. Very large prints sometimes are set up in 10% of the final size. *Probably* because some software cannot create artwork that big or to reduce file size.

It is ok to ask for clarification though. Print websites often have guides for that too.

Comment: So if they asked for 500x500mm 300dpi CMYK and I create just that set up In indesign then that is 100% scale?

Comment: @Lukas_T I would yes, that should be a file size they could easily manage.